# 50 questions before I can comment?

Tags: discussion

Do I have this straight.
I need to ask enough questions to get 50 reputations before I can place a comment?

Comment: I guess somethings are only seen from a computer and not a phone.

Comment: No, you need enough *upvotes on your posts* to generate 50 reputation. Questions get +5 reputation points for every upvote and answers get +10. They each get -2 for every downvote. So you only need a maximum of 10 upvotes and no downvotes. Not too hard to get. Five good questions at most.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of.

You can always comment on your own questions and answers, but you do need 50 reputation earned before you can make comments on other people's posts.

This is sort of a safeguard against spam, but also an incentive to learn how to site works a little bit before you get full access. Pretty much all permissions, in sort of descending order of importance (and ascending order of trust required to use) are reputation based. For instance, at 2000 reputation you can freely edit posts without needing to go through the review queues.

Comment: I guess it takes some serious concentration to figure it out. So far I like it tho because that is what I like when searching for answers to biblical questions. Just straight answers to my questions on that.

Comment: @Winifred That's the idea. Happy asking. To help you get started, see [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409)

Comment: @Winifred And just for completeness, there are help pages: [Help on reputation](/help/whats-reputation) | [Help on privileges](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges)